# async NPM module not executing setTimeout for each item in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using the [async NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) and have written the following program:

```
var async = require('async');

var arr = [1,2,3,4];

async.each(arr, function (item) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('item: ', item);
  }, 1000);
}, function (error) {
  console.log('error', error);
});
```

I expected the console logs to show up after every 1 sec but it shows all the logs at once after 1 sec.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The setTimeout function is given a timeout of 1 second and they are all set up at one time, so they'll all end close to the same time. You'd have to increase the timeout for each one if you want them to happen every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eachSeries` instead of `each` and pass a callback function:

```
var async = require('async');

var arr = [1,2,3,4];

async.eachSeries(arr, function (item, callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('item: ', item);
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}, function (error) {
  console.log('error', error);
});
```

`eachSeries` is the same as `each` but runs only a single async operation at a time.